# Aws codebuild failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I have created repository and pushed the code by using aws code commit. Whenever i made changes and push it to repository,it has updated. But when i used to do build by using aws code build, it is failing bec not able to find the buildspec.yml and pom.xml.

Please find the attachment as My yaml file(buildspec.yml) and my pom.xml file in root..

I have tried with 2 scenarios in awscodebuild.

1. buildspec.yml in my code, but it is failed in downloaded-source and indicating the error below
   CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src408069893/src/awsgitrepo
   CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src408069893/src/awsgitrepo/buildspec.yml - No such file or directory.
2. When i tried with insert build commands in awscodebuild, it is failed and stating that

/codebuild/output/src408069893/src/awsgitrepo/ - The goal you specified requires a project, but there is no pom in this directory.

Both error indicating the samepath and missing files.

So could you please let me know how to avoid this failure. Is there a way to set the path for code build to pick up the source files.Want to know about the CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR which one how to set it and the need of CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR. [image]

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem with aws pipeline test project and it turned out that the structure of my repository on github was bad.

```
    You need to have (root directory name)
      -- my-web-app
           |-- src    
           |     `-- main
           |           |-- resources
           |           `-- webapp
           |                 |-- WEB-INF
           |                 |     `-- web.xml
           |                 `-- index.jsp
           |-- buildspec.yml
           `-- pom.xml
```

as it say here:

[Create a file named buildspec.yml with the following contents. Store the file in the (root directory name)/my-web-app directory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-runtime-versions.html#sample-runtime-update-version)

To sum up, in order to aws code build find your pom and buildspec you need to have correct git repo structure as: repository_name > [src, pom.xml, buildspec.yml...] and NOT: repository name > root_repo_dir > [src, pom.xml, buildspec.yml...]

Hope it helped!

Comment: this was my issue, thought I was in the root directory but was not

Answer (score 1):

From the error log, it seems the pom.xml and the buildspec.yml are not in the root folder. Try inserting this command `find . -name pom.xml` in scenario 2 to locate the pom.xml.

Comment: Hi Yong, Thank you for the input. I have tried in scenarion 2 by inserting build comments but it has failed. please have a look on this and help me on this issue..

Comment: version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo nothing to do in the install phase
      
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo nothing to do in the pre_build phase
     
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - find . -name pom.xml
      - mvn clean
      - mvn test
  post_build:
    commands:
      - mvn install
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - target/Struts2Hibernate3Spring3Tile2Integration.war. But same error occured

Comment: I ran the command and gives the below response. So where do i need to have the pom.xml                                                                   [Container] 2018/06/28 04:51:23 Running command find / -iname 'pom.xml'
/codebuild/output/src389124914/src/git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Code-commit/Struts2Hibernate3Spring3Tile2Integration/pom.xml
/codebuild/readonly/src/Struts2Hibernate3Spring3Tile2Integration/pom.xml and getting the same error

Comment: Could you please guide me on this

Comment: I guess you need to run you build commands inside that folder. You can `cd /codebuild/readonly/src/Struts2Hibernate3Spring3Tile2Integration`  first; before running other commands

Comment: Hi..I have tried and getting error as  [Container] 2018/06/29 05:57:44 Running command  cd /codebuild/readonly/src/Webportal/pom.xml
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: cd: can't cd to /codebuild/readonly/src/Webportal/pom.xml....This is the expectation [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory(/codebuild/output/src660249895/src/git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/javarepository). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> Expecting pom should be in the directory. i tried cp to move the pom.Failedpls help

Comment: Hi Yong, MVN clean install command successfully executed. I placed the pom.xml in javarepostiory (repo) as it is expecting (/codebuild/output/src660249895/src/git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/javarepository)